# C# WPF Scrollable container for usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've looked all over and have been unable to find a solution to my problem. My entire approach might be off and I could start over if I'm simply tackling this the wrong way.

I have a WPF window with a header, a listbox, an a footer. I want to programatically add n number of user controls to the listbox and have the listbox itself be scrollable (not the entire window). I also want to turn off what happens when you click an item in the listbox (the background highlights blue - I want it to change the background of the user control now treat it as a big listbox item) Really a listbox might even be the wrong thing.

I've tried stackpanels, scrollpanels, and a half dozen other approaches. Listbox just happens to be what I'm using now. I have a dozen different types of usercontrols and based on business logic some combination of them needs to be displayed, so really I need a scrollable usercontrol container where I can determine which one, if any, has been clicked.

Here is the XAML for MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LayoutTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:customUserControls="clr-namespace:LayoutTest.Properties"
        Title="Layout Sample" Height="Auto" MaxWidth="600" MinWidth="600" Width="600"  ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="393*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,210,5">Header</TextBlock>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstPanels" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,17"/>        
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,210,5">Footer</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the XAML for UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="LayoutTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="500" Padding="0" Margin="10">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="OrangeRed" CornerRadius="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="imgLogo" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100" />
            <Grid MinWidth="400">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="108*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="104*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="188*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="35*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="xxxxx:" Margin="5,2,2,2" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Text="xxxxx" Margin="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="xxxxx:" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,2,2,2" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="xxxxxx" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2" />
                <CheckBox Content="xxxxxx" Grid.Row="3" Name="chkSkipConfiguration" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,112,5" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                <Button Content="xxxxx" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"  Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" Margin="0,0,19,0"  />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And lastly in the constructor for MainWindow.xaml.cs there is the following snippet to create 10 instances of the user control:

```
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lstPanels.Items.Add(new UserControl1());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First give your ListBox a height and width, either explicitly or by Stretching it within a container.  With your ListBox you can define a vertical scrollbar using ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible".  If you have a height defined then it should automatically enable scrolling as your added items extend past that height.

As far as the highlighting goes, try this setter.  Just place it in a style targeted for the ListBoxItem type:

```
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
           <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent">
              <ContentPresenter />
           </Border>
           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                 <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>Transparent</Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Trigger>
           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Comment: I was able to get the listbox to scroll, so thank you for that, but I'm stuck with this style. Using this markup selecting a listitem removes the default blue background, so that is definitely an improvement. What would I need to change for it to set the background color of the UserControl (which is what the listboxitem contains) instead? The UserControl, as shown in my original example, has a orange border. It would be nice if when that item is clicked I was able to shade the space within the border of the usercontrol. Thanks!

Comment: If you leave that style on the ListBoxItem, I believe you can achieve what you want by adding a property to your control called IsSelected.  If you handle the PreviewMouseDown or PreviewMouseUp of the Border element, and set IsSelected to !IsSelected each event, you can then add a DataTrigger for the IsSelected property to change the background of the Border or the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the cuff... Is there a reason you can't wrap things with a ScrollViewer and have the contained controls respond to the clicks by passing messages? ScrollViewer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx

Comment: I tried scrollviewers at one point but that scrolled the entire page. I couldn't find any way to get a bunch of usercontrol's in the middle of a page to scroll while keeping the header and footer visible at all times.

The example in the document has scrollviewer as the top level element. It might be possible but I couldn't get the syntax right when I tried it

Comment: I just tried replacing the listbox with a scrollviewer and placed a stackpanel inside the scrollviewer. I then added my usercontrols to the stackpanel.children instead of listbox.items and got the same result.